# Which gods are allowed to be worshipped in a banalinga?

Tags: banalinga

Does a Hindu only worship lord shiva in the banalinga or can they worships goddess like Saraswati, Laxmi , Kali ,Ganesha and Skanda on it? Please give some reference to some authentic texts and paragraphs . Thank you.

Comment: Any other deities can be invoked and worshipped in a Banalinga.

Comment: What do you mean by any other deities @Rickross?

Comment: Sorry for creating the confusion .. I meant all deities can be invoked and worshipped in Banalinga but in usual practice it is not done so. Because if one is worshipping any Vaishnava deity they will naturally use Shaligrama instead of a Banalinga and so on.But it can be done.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rickross.